# Using the particle と or the particle に with あう

Tags: word-choice, particle-に, particle-と

I've always thought that the only particle which is correct to use with 会う is に：

> 明日あなた**に**会います。

But I've come across the sentence:

> きのう田中さん**と**会いました。

Is it correct? If it is, when shall we use と with 会う and when shall we use に?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/62688

Answer (score 6):

と is a rather symmetric particle overall: 'I met Tanaka' has the sense of 'Tanaka and I met'.

に is less symmetric: e.g. I went to Tanaka's office to see him. It may also be a difference of status, rather than of motion: 社長と会いました seems pretentious because it creates an equality of sorts between the CEO and me.