# と会ってくれる feels unnatural

Tags: grammar, meaning

**1)** 先生は私と会ってくれる。

How is this sentence correct?

[先生は私と会ってくれる] this setence feels unnatural to me becauseと会う means subject and person(me) are going to meet each other so how くれる can be used in this setence. But if I use に会う It means only subject is doing a favor of going to meet the person. Therefore, personに会ってあげる/くれる is grammartically correct but not と会ってあげる/くれる

**In conclusion,**

**先生は私と会ってくれる = incorrect + unnatural**

**先生は私に会ってくれる = correct + natural**

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/65633/using-the-particle-%e3%81%a8-or-the-particle-%e3%81%ab-with-%e3%81%82%e3%81%86

Answer (score 2):

So, I think this is confusing you because you are attaching the `に` to `くれる` and not `会う`. While that's a reasonable interpretation and you could certainly argue for parsing the sentence out like this: `(私に)(会ってくれる)`, I think it will be easier to understand if you parse it like this: `(私に会って)(くれる)`.

Concretely, the important thing is that while `に` can be used to mark the recipient associated with `くれる`, you can also attach `くれる` to all kinds of clauses including those that have no `に` or contain other uses of `に`. For example, if we look at the below sentence:

> 友達が私の郵便箱に手紙を入れてくれた
> (My friend put a letter in my mailbox for me)

This `に` is clearly not marking the recipient of `くれる`, as it's the speaker and not the mailbox who is receiving the favor here. If you can accept that the `に` or `と` in your case is attaching to the verb `会う`, either structure should make sense. You can read about the differences between `に会う` and `と会う` [here](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/65633/using-the-particle-%E3%81%A8-or-the-particle-%E3%81%AB-with-%E3%81%82%E3%81%86), but if you want further evidence that both of these are reasonable you can see that there are plenty of Google search results for both [に会ってくれる](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk01xxHY7_S9b0ibPcVjNRItUIlJkFA%3A1608871504488&ei=UG7lX_emHZjM-Qax2pKgBA&q=%22%E3%81%AB%E4%BC%9A%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%22&oq=%22%E3%81%AB%E4%BC%9A%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQA1C-A1j1BWCHB2gAcAB4AIABtAGIAdUCkgEDMC4ymAEAoAEBqgEHZ3dzLXdpesABAQ&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwj3jo60qejtAhUYZt4KHTGtBEQQ4dUDCA0&uact=5) and [と会ってくれる](https://www.google.com/search?sxsrf=ALeKk01QpKb6m2pJD_wwWcpaMHJMwwd8Gg%3A1608871506195&ei=Um7lX4CzC4eNoATLgJm4Aw&q=%22%E3%81%A8%E4%BC%9A%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%22&oq=%22%E3%81%A8%E4%BC%9A%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E3%81%8F%E3%82%8C%E3%82%8B%22&gs_lcp=CgZwc3ktYWIQAzoICAAQBxAEEB46BggAEAcQHjoGCAAQBBAlUMsLWLAQYPcSaABwAHgAgAGxAYgBogWSAQMwLjSYAQCgAQGqAQdnd3Mtd2l6wAEB&sclient=psy-ab&ved=0ahUKEwiApPa0qejtAhWHBogKHUtABjcQ4dUDCA0&uact=5).

Some of the `と` are conditional and a lot of the `に` are either marking time or part of `のに`, but if you scroll a bit you can find examples of both particles attached to people who are being met.

Comment: I got the impression that the OP **was** associating the particle with 会う. The problem, as I understood it, was that when you use と with 会う it implies more of a mutual willingness to meet, whereas with に it is more one sided (I've explained that really badly, but there is a difference, right?). The problem then is, is it acceptable to use くれる which is a one sided, giving, kind of verb with と会う which is more of a mutual thing?

Comment: Yeah, that did occur to me as the other possibility. It's a little harder to tackle that one concretely except by saying "we can see from Google search results that people do use both". Given that we know people use both, hopefully the remainder of the question can be answered by the linked question about と vs に with 会う.